# How to get an object value out of the array so they are elements of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have an array of objects. I want to create another array that **only** contains the key values of the objects that are inside of the previous array. Additionally, I don't know how many elements the x array will contain, it's depended on the user. Is there any way? I tried mapping, filtering, `object.values()`, but everything returns a new array of objects.

```
x = [{1: 182}, {2: 912}, {3: 51}, …]
y = [182, 912, 51, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array with `Array.flatMap()`, and get an array of values from each object using `Object.values()`. The flatMap would flatten the sub-arrays to a single array.

```js
const x = [{1: 182}, {2: 912}, {3: 51}]

const result = x.flatMap(Object.values)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I haven't heard of flatMap, always something new to learn. Thank you :)